# Portable way to load the C standard library in Python ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes, libc

Is there a portable way to load the C standard library (`libc.so`, `libc.dylib`) in Python ctypes? Should I just use `if`/`elif` statements about the result of [`platform.system()`](http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html#platform.system) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ctypes` library doesn't offer anything of that nature so an `if` statement is just what you need.

Comment: @eryksun: As the documentation notes, the exact behaviour is platform dependent - on windows, "a call like `find_library("c")` will fail and return None".

Comment: Windows ships with msvcrt.dll, that's the best option